# using strcpy to assign value to structure returns segment error

Tags: c

I have the following code and I am trying to assign a value to the structure name but it is returning me segment core error. Why is that?

```
struct group {
    char *name;
    struct user *users;
    struct xct *xcts;
    struct group *next;
};

int add_group(Group **group_list_ptr, const char *group_name) {
    Group *newGroup = malloc(sizeof(Group));
    strcpy(newGroup->name, group_name);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `malloc`-ed the `struct`, but you did not `malloc` the string. The pointer inside the `struct` is uninitialized, so you cannot `strcpy` anything into it yet.

You have to allocate memory for your string, assign that memory to `name`, and only then do `strcpy`:

```
Group *newGroup = malloc(sizeof(Group));
newGroup->name = malloc(strlen(group_name)+1); // +1 for '\0' terminator
strcpy(newGroup->name, group_name);
```